# Set of conditions for Finite Automata transitions

Tags: automata

What kind of Finite Automata supports set of conditions for transaction from state A to state B? For example, if (a && b && c) then A -> B.

To make it even harder, let's say that we receive one condition at a time.

of course it could be done with DFA, but that will lead to state explosion

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you use NFA or DFA as you can subsequently apply the so-called powerset construction in order to minimize it. This yields the **smallest possible** automaton for your defined language.